# Material UI Switch: Visually show the switch as enabled when the value of "checked" is false

Tags: javascript, material-ui, formik

I'm using Material UI Switches with Formik. Whenever I "enable" the switch it automatically marks the value in Formik as "true" and when I "disable" the switch it marks the value in Formik as "false".

I'm looking to invert the UI switch so when my Formik value is "true" the switch displays a "false" value. I've tried modifying the "checked" value on the switch to no avail, and I've started playing with the styling properties of the switch as well.

Any ideas would be appriciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two important things I noticed when working with Formik and Material UI:

- name prop that is passed to Field component from Formik will be the one used to control the value of the component. This means you can use the values prop to access this field's value by using the name prop
- checked prop passed to FormControlLabel component is used to control the UI

You can pass the Switch component from Material UI to the component prop of the Field component as seen below

```
<FormControlLabel
  control={
    <Field
      name="toggleMe"
      component={Switch}
      onChange={handleToggle}
    />
  }
  label="Toggle Here"
  checked={values.toggleMe}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

What I understand is that you want to invert the behaviour of the switch component, so when the Formik value is `true` the switch should display `false` and vice versa.

If that's the case, why not just take the negative of the Formik value?

```js
 <Switch {...label} checked={!formikValue} onChange={handleChange} />
```

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicswitches-demo-material-ui-forked-zpf9kk?file=/demo.js:378-447)

Comment: This doesnt answer the question the example doesnt relate to `Formik` the library

Comment: Formik is a library https://formik.org/ . You just named your state variable `Formik`

Comment: I know what Formik is, the question clearly states the intended behaviour is to invert the value, and I quote "my Formik value", hence, my use of  "formikValue". In addition to that, I clearly stated which assumption I based my answer on.